# KNX and KNXnet/IP implementation in Python

Tags: python, home-automation, knx

I am looking high and low for anything related to [KNX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KNX_%28standard%29) implementation in Python, especially KNXnet/IP. So far I couldn't find anything. I know there are few projects written in Java but I thought I'd give it a shot asking here before I start porting code from other languages.

Also, does anyone know of any free documentation of the KNX standard, its data structures and  KNXnet/IP? The official documentation from the KNX association is ridiculously expensive, especially for something supposed to be an "open" standard.

thanks

Comment: Was looking for something like that myself and couldn't really find anything so I ended up writing something myself: https://github.com/mfussenegger/knx

you could also take a look at https://mknx.github.io/smarthome/ which has some knx support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The KNX association have released the Falcon Runtime Developer kit but I think you can only get it if you are a KNX member. it doesnt supports Python but hey, its something i guess.

in regards to the documentation I could probably help.
is there a PM function on this site or something to give me your emails address?

Comment: there is no PM on s-O. i would also be interested in KNX docs anyhow

Comment: Also the documentation is available to KNX association members, however, membership is very expensive and way beyond what one would pay for hobby DIY project. I am not comfortable posting my real email here but I created a temp email address: barduck@trashmail.net . Please drop me an email. Thank you very much!

Comment: if you receive the docs can you post a comment to this so that i will provide you my mail address?

Comment: Great! Thank you very much. It contains useful information about the KNX bus and telegram structure. What I am still missing is documentation of KNXnet/IP. Do you happens to have that too maybe?

Comment: I don't have any more info on KNX/IP sorry. if you find anything, post it here as I would be interested to find out too.

Comment: I released my project (including a KNXnet/IP implementation) on github (see profile page). It's not written in Python but you can use it to take a look at the protocol specific parts.

Comment: anyone has a documentation ?

Answer (score 3):

There is the open-source [BCUSDK](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bcusdk/) software stack for KNX which has a C-based system daemon ([eibd](http://www.auto.tuwien.ac.at/~mkoegler/index.php/eibd)) with clients (Unix and TCP-socket based) for multiple languages (Python is one). I've written the [Ruby](https://github.com/ekarak/eibd_ruby) and [Lua](https://github.com/ekarak/eibd_lua) client libraries as well, and I'm using it for day-to-day hacking with KNX.

Also, there is [OpenRemote](http://openremote.org) which has lots of information on KNXnet/IP and some Java classes that could get you started, if you wanted to, from scratch.

Comment: Thanks. I am familiar with those projects but I still hoped there was somewhere a hidden native Python implementation that I can't find. Looks like my choices are either implementing it myself from scratch, switching to Java for my project or using additional layer like the BCUSDK and interfacing with it.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to have a look a this (if by that time you are still looking for such a library) : https://github.com/leadrien/knxnet
This allows me to command KNX devices through an IP/KNX interface pretty well.

Alexandre

Comment: Do you still need the ETS software if using Python ?

Comment: You still need it to configure your KNX devices

Comment: So I assume then the ETS software is still required?

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile there is an open source Python 3 implementation of KNX IP https://github.com/XKNX/xknx

The documentation of the protocol can be downloaded after (free) registration from https://my.knx.org